# Parse a simple key=value config file in C

Tags: c, parsing, file, configuration

> Write a program that should read a file formatted **strictly** like
>   this below:
>
> ```
> $ cat sample
>
> bingo=2
> bingo2=939
> bingo3=text
> ```
>
> The left and right side of `=` are consecutively parameter name and
>   its respective value. The values can be integer or strings. Each parameter is 
>   separated by a newline. The parameter name and its value will not be more than 
>   127 bytes.

This program is fed an input search token, and if found, `parse_param_file()` will fill the input arguments with string or integer value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define TEXT "sample"

/* 
 * Function: parse_param_file
 * Arguments:
 * token    - param name that needs to be looked up
 * buf      - buffer for string value. Pass NULL if unwanted
 * buf_int  - buffer for integer value. Pass NULL if unwanted
 * filename - string formatted path to the file 
 */
int parse_param_file(const char *token, char **buf, int *buf_int,
        const char *filename) {
    if (!token || (!buf && !buf_int)) {
        printf("%s: invalid args\n", __FUNCTION__);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("%s: %s not found\n", __FUNCTION__, filename);
        return 1;
    }
    char *left = malloc(128);
    char *right = malloc(128);
    char *dlim_ptr, *end_ptr;
    char fbuf[256];
    while (fgets(fbuf, 256, f)) {
        dlim_ptr = strstr(fbuf, "=");
        end_ptr = strstr(dlim_ptr, "\n");
        strncpy(left, fbuf, dlim_ptr - fbuf);
        strncpy(right, dlim_ptr + 1, end_ptr - dlim_ptr - 1);
        if (strcmp(left, token) == 0) {
            /* Param found */
            if (buf != NULL)
                *buf = strdup(right);
            if (buf_int != NULL)
                *buf_int = atoi(right);
            fclose(f);
            free(left);
            free(right);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("%s: Param not found in %s\n", __FUNCTION__, filename);
    free(left);
    free(right);
    return 1;
}

/* How to use parse_param_file() */
int main(void) {
    char *buf = malloc(128);
    int val = 0;

    /* Test 1 */
    if (parse_param_file("bingo2", NULL, NULL, TEXT))
        fprintf(stderr, "parse_param_file() failed\n");
    printf("buf : %s\n", buf);
    printf("int : %d\n", val);
    /* Test 2 */
    if (parse_param_file("bingo3242", NULL, &val, TEXT))
        fprintf(stderr, "parse_param_file() failed\n");
    printf("buf : %s\n", buf);
    printf("int : %d\n", val);
    /* You must clear *buf and val if you want to reuse them as args again */
    /* Test 3 */
    if (parse_param_file("bingo3", &buf, &val, TEXT))
        fprintf(stderr, "parse_param_file() failed\n");
    printf("buf : %s\n", buf);
    printf("int : %d\n", val);

    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

#### Interface

I'm not overly fond of the interface you've defined to the function. I think trying to combine reading integers and reading strings into a single function makes it more difficult to use. For most C code, I think the old guiding principle of UNIX ("do one thing, and do it well") provides excellent guidance. As such, I'd probably have two separate functions, one for reading a string, the other for reading a number.

I haven't tested it to be sure, but at first glance it also looks like if you ask to read a number, it does a poor job of signalling failure. For example, if your file has: `foo=0` and you try to read `foo` as a number, it'll set the number to 0, and return 0. But if the file contains `foo=Joe` instead, it looks to me like it'll do exactly the same.

I'd prefer that if it couldn't convert the rest of the line after the `=` to a number that it return 1 to indicate that it has failed.

#### Memory Allocation

Since you only use our `left` and `right` inside of your function, and free them again before returning, there's probably no need to allocate them on the heap. You can just allocate them as local arrays, and use them. The obvious exception to this would be if you were targeting a tiny micro-controller that might well have less than 256 bytes available on the stack. In that case, however, you usually won't have a file system either, so the entire function becomes irrelevant.

#### Standard Library

I think judicious use of `fscanf` can simplify the code quite a bit.

For reading a string, it seems like the obvious interface would be to just return the value part of the pair, and if it's not found, return a NULL pointer:

```
char *read_string(FILE *file, char const *desired_name) { 
    char name[128];
    char val[128];

    while (fscanf(file, "%127[^=]=%127[^\n]%*c", name, val) == 2) {
        if (0 == strcmp(name, desired_name)) {
            return strdup(val);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

When reading a number, we probably need something closer to your original interface, with a return value to indicate success/failure, and receive a pointer to an int where we write the value (if it's found):

```
int read_int(FILE *file, char const *desired_name, int *ret) {
    char *temp = read_string(file, desired_name);

    char *stop;
    *ret = strtol(temp, &stop, 10);
    int ret_val = stop == NULL || *stop != '\0';
    free(temp);
    return ret_val;
}
```

Note that as it stands right now, the return value reflects converting the *entire* remainder of the line (everything after the `=`) to the desired number. If part of it can be converted, that part will be written to the destination, but the return will still indicate failure. For example, if you had `foo=1234abcd`, attempting to read `foo` as a number would give you `1234`, but return 1 because the `abcd` part couldn't be converted.

It would also be possible to simply ignore any trailing garbage, so `foo=1234abcd` would read the `1234` part, and return 0 to signal success:

```
int read_int(FILE *file, char const *desired_name, int *ret) {
    char *temp = read_string(file, desired_name);

    char *stop;
    *ret = strtol(temp, &stop, 10);
    int ret_val = stop == temp;
    free(temp);
    return ret_val;
}
```

In this case, we just need to check that at least one character was converted, in which case `stop` will have be advanced at least one character after the input.

Comment: Given that both functions will be used together, the function `read_int` could accept the value string as a parameter, and therefore we have one less strdup&free.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: It could, but since the original returned a string allocated with `strdup`, I treated that as a requirement. But you're right, that it's probably worth some thought whether to treat it as a requirement, or require the caller to pass the address/size of a buffer instead.

Comment: "*The obvious exception to this would be if you were targeting a tiny micro-controller that might well have less than 256 bytes available on the stack*" -- in that case you probably won't have a heap either, and those buffers will be statically allocated.

Comment: `stop == NULL` in `int ret_val = stop == NULL || *stop != '\0';` is strange as it is never true without UB. I suspect you wanted `int ret_val = stop ==temp || *stop != '\0';`.   You may want to look into `errno` and truncation of `long` into `int` too.

Comment: `return stop == temp;` is UB.  Do not use `temp` after `free(temp);` - even if to just compare pointers.

Comment: @chux: I've heard that before, but have yet to find or see anybody else find a normative reference for the claim. Appendix J.2 does say (more or less) the same as you have, but J.2 itself is informative, not normative, and gives §7.22.3 as the supposed normative reference--but although I've reread §7.22.3 dozens of times over the years, I've yet to find anything there that states, implies, or even hints that this is actually true. Dereferencing the pointer after freeing is clearly UB--but comparing the value...nothing normative seems to support the claim.

Comment: @JerryCoffin C11 6.2.4  has "The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.", so after `free()`, the value is _indeterminate_ (either an unspecified value or a trap representation).   `stop == temp` after `free(temp)` can lead to a trap - e.g. "no further operations".  Perhaps not UB, yet still better to avoid a potential trap and perform any compare before `free(temp)`.

Answer (score 7):

### `__func__`

Unlike `__FUNCTION__`, `__func__` is standard C since C99.  Some compilers might not support C99 and therefore in those compilers you have to use whatever they provide, but if your compiler supports C99, you should use `__func__`.  If you have a crappy compiler, think about using a better one.

---

### magic numbers

[What is a magic number, and why is it bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/6872717)

Don't use any numbers different than 0, 1, or 2 in your code.  The only place where numbers deserve to go is in constant macros like this:

```
#define MAX_STRLEN   (127)
```

Note:  As Roland Illig pointed out in his comment, this is still a magic number, but it is already much better than the alternative.  To improve it, a comment about why 127 and not another number, would be very appropriate just above the definition.

---

### `BUFSIZ`

When you create a buffer, and you don't need a strict size (when you need a very large buffer, or you are short of memory), you can use `BUFSIZ` which is defined in `<stdio.h>`, which is around 1KiB~4KiB.

```
#include <stdio.h>

...

char fbuf[BUFSIZ];
```

---

### `ARRAY_SIZE()`

Use this macro wherever possible.

Typically defined as: `#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr)  (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))`

It makes your code safer:

If you ever change the size of an array, it will be updated, while if you hardcoded the size as a magic number, you will have to update every number, and if you hardcoded it as a macro (sometimes, ARRAY_SIZE can't be used, and this is the only possibility), if you change the name of the macro, you will have to update it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr)     (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))

...

char fbuf[BUFSIZ];
while (fgets(fbuf, ARRAY_SIZE(fbuf), f)) {
```

Note: Never use `sizeof` where `ARRAY_SIZE` should be used. It's very unsafe, because if an array ever changes to be a pointer (for example if it is a function parameter), ARRAY_SIZE will raise a warning on recent compilers, while sizeof will give wrong results, and produce hard to find bugs.

Comment: MAX_STRLEN is still as magic as 127. From the context it is clear that the 127 is a maximum. The question remains: of which string? Every string in the whole program? Inventing an unexpressive name for a magic number doesn't make it less magic.

Comment: @RolandIllig Above such things, a comment would be appropriate. But magic numbers are better kept together in the beginning of the file.  I wrote that name, because in this simple program, every processed string (not the fgets buffer, for which I would use BUFSIZ) seems to use 127.  One of the main advantages is that you don't repeat 127 in all the code.

Answer (score 6):

Your program crashes when it reads a line from the parameters file that doesn't contain an `=` sign.

The name of the macro `TEXT` is misleading. It doesn't contain a text but a filename.

Whenever you output an error message, it belongs on `stderr` instead of `stdout`. To do this, replace `printf(` with `fprintf(stderr,`.

Answer (score 4):

**Undefined behavior**

`strcmp(left, token)`, `strdup(right)` are UB as `left, right` do not certainly point to *strings* (*null character* terminated arrays).

Could replace

```
strncpy(left, fbuf, dlim_ptr - fbuf);
```

with below to insure null termination.

```
sprintf(left, "%.*s", (int) (dlim_ptr - fbuf), fbuf);
```

Comment: Another replacement to strncpy could be `strscpy`, which should be written because it's not even an extension.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito `strscpy()`  is a reasonable alternative yet `strscpy()` is not part of the standard C library. I'd classify it as an extension to standard C.

Comment: A great extension that no compiler or library provides. AFAIK, only the Linux kernel has it :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first some comments.  I’ll add code if you want - just can’t do it effectively from my phone.

1. Basically any string function that doesn’t take the length of the string is problematic.  It has the potential to read beyond the end of the buffer.  atoi should be replaced with strtol, strcmp with strncmp, ...

   2. Allocating fixed sizes of memory, just to release the fixed sizes of memory is pointless.  Don’t do that.  Now having the allocation and the free in the same function is very beneficial, do that over allocating something buried in a function and remembering to deallocate it later.
2. The standard string library is very slow.  It is ok for very simple things, as long as you only need to do them once.  If you need to do this faster, you might want to use a tool like lex or flex to do so.  You can also write your own lexical scanner based on deterministic automata - it’s a good exercise, but flex is much easier.

Ok, I’ll have to fix my formatting later.

Comment: Links to "lex" or "flex" would be appropriate.  Is that a program or is it a library that can be used from C?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Lex and flex are programs that generate lexical analyzers. The programs generated are state machines using tables. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software) https://www.gnu.org/software/flex/

Answer (score -3):

Well I don't know exactly what `strstr` does, but I would've used `strtok` (string tokenizer) somewhere in the process as its purpose is to find delimiters and split strings there.

Comment: Here you have what `strstr()` does: [`man strstr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html): It searches a substring in a string.